# how to select a styled-component and access its property (ex: offsetHeight)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using React and styled-components. Let's say I have this component :

```
...

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
`

export default class MyComponent extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledDiv>Hello World</StyledDiv>
    )
  }
}
```

I would like to select this div in `componentDidMount()` and access its property, like offsetHeight.

Normally, I would use document.querySelector().offsetHeight, but I don't know what is the wright approach with styled-components.

I tried to pass a className like this :

```
...

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
`

export default class MyComponent extends React.component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const test = document.querySelector('.testDiv');
    console.log(test);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyledDiv className="testDiv">Hello World</StyledDiv>
    )
  }
}
```

But the console.log output that I get is `null`. 
I'm able to get it via the browser's console, though...

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using regular `ref`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ref = React.createRef();
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.ref.current.offsetHeight);
  }
  render() {
    return <StyledDiv ref={this.ref}>Hello World</StyledDiv>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-tdd-25g72)